# Trazer apenas certas quantidades de informações do banco MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso trazer apenas 6 registos do banco de dados para mostrar na View,  em vez de trazer apenas 6 registos, ta trazendo todos.

O código é o seguinte:

```
public PartialViewResult Cursos()
{
    ViewBag.Cursos = new CursoRepositorio().BuscarTodos().Take(6).ToArray();
    return PartialView();
}
```

Comment: podes mostrar a função buscar todos? e a partial view

Comment: A buscar todos é `public IEnumerable<TEntity> BuscarTodos()
        {
            return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }` e a partial view so tem um foreach que vo monta com os 6 dados do banco, nada de mais

Comment: Grande erro!!! uma vez que você já foi no banco e retornou todos os dados  (((return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToList();))) tente alterar isso com a quantidade que você quer antes de lança a consulta contra o banco de dados.

Comment: Mais uma grande falha causada por tentar implementar *repository pattern* em cima do EF.

Answer (score 1):

Na sua consulta do Entity Framework é necessário informar quantos registros seram listados ...

Tente criar um objeto

```
DaoCurso
```

E utilize uma lista desse curso

```
List<DaoCurso> curso = null;

curso = entity.TBCURSO.Select(x=> new DaoCurso() { idcurso =x.idcurso , nomecurso = x.nomecurso ).Take(6).ToList();
```

E adicione isso na sua ViewBag;

```
ViewBag.Cursos = curso;
```